# Не работает ListIterator

Tags: java, коллекции

Простой пример, уже с ума схожу, не могу понять, что не так(вчера работало...). Подскажите, почему данный кусок кода не выводит результата.

```
public class Collections {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        al.add(1);
        al.add(2);
        al.add(3);
        al.add(4);
        al.add(5);
        al.add(6);
        ListIterator<Integer> li=al.listIterator();

        while(li.hasPrevious()){
            System.out.println(li.previous());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li.hasPrevious()` - выдает `true` если итератор может сдвинуться на один элемент назад. При этом изначально итератор указывает на нулевой элемент и соответственно у него нет -1 элемента, поэтому `li.hasPrevious()` всегда возвращает `false` в твоём случае.

Обычно используются методы `hasNext()` и `next()`. Если же тебе необходимо именно так пройти по листу, то получай итератор так `al.listIterator(al.size())` и твой код будет выводить элементы листа в обратном порядке.

Comment: Делал по Шилдту... странно... но спасибо

Comment: @Nemezis16 я бы не советовал Шилдта. лучше Хорстманн и Эккель

Comment: Начинать лучше с Эккеля.